# Give all rows appear in another table at least specific number of times

Tags: sql, join, group-by, having

I am using the sample [database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join) and I want to write a query on the tables `Customers` and `Orders` that gives all the customers which have made more than 2 Orders. Although I achive that with the query:

```
Select Customers.*
From Customers
Where Customers.CustomerID IN(
Select Orders.CustomerID
From Orders
Group by Orders.CustomerID
Having count(*)>2
);
```

I cannot understand why the query:

```
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*)>2;
```

cannot give the same results. The message from the database is:

"Cannot group on fields selected with '*' (Customers)."

I had though the impression that it should work, since `Customers.CustomerID` is included on the demanded columns in `Select` statement. What is the problem and how could I modify the second query in order to work, even though it excecutes probably superfluous statements?

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
SQL GROUP BY Syntax

SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;
```

So for using aggregating, you need to specify which columns you are aggregating by, and for that you cannot use `*`

You would have to specifically specify the columns in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, it works but it gives only the IDs. In order to get full information, I need to put it in a subquery and to check match it on the outer query with IN or EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the columns you need in `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName
HAVING COUNT(*)>2;
```

Comment: It works on these particular tables, but I would like to know if there would be a problem if two Customers had the same name. Probably not, since both are grouped. Am I right?

Comment: You right, but in this case you should remove `Customers.CustomerID` from `SELECT` and from `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is formed of two queries actually

The second part is used for determining returning customers by listing CustomerID

```
        Select o.CustomerID
    From Sales.SalesOrderHeader o
    Group by o.CustomerID
    Having count(*)>2
```

And the first part displays Customer details by using returning customer list gained by the second query

```
Select c.*
From Sales.Customer c
Where 
c.CustomerID IN(
    ...
);
```

It is not possible to return all customer data while trying to fetch dublicate customer ID's using Group By syntax on Order table

But instead of Group By, SQL aggregate functions (Count function below) with PARTITION BY clause can be used here
Please check the tutorial http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx and have a look at the following query

```
select * from (
SELECT distinct
    c.*,
    COUNT(o.SalesOrderID) over (partition by c.CustomerId) cnt
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader o
INNER JOIN Sales.Customer c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
) t where cnt > 1
```